# How to use strpos to match most of a word?

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo out the names of the measuring units for each array key.

Issue is that, sometimes there are key values that has abbreviations, as I've shown in the last key value in the haystack variable.

```
$haystack = array(
    '15.1 ounces white chocolate',
    '1 ounce olive oil',
    '½ cup whipping cream',
    '1 tablespoon shredded coconut',
    '1 tablespoon lemon',
    '1 oz water'
);

$needles = 
    array(
        '0' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'cup',
            'abbreviation' => 'c'
        ), 
        '1' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'name' => 'ounce',
            'abbreviation' => 'oz'
        ), 
        '2' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'name' => 'teaspoon',
            'abbreviation' => 'tsp'
        ), 
        '3' => array(
            'id' => '4',
            'name' => 'tablespoon',
            'abbreviation' => 'tbsp'
    )
);

foreach($haystack as $hay){
    foreach($needles as $needle){
        if(strpos($hay, $needle['name']) !== false || strpos($hay, $needle['abbreviation']) !== false){
            $names[] = $needle['id'];
        }
    }
}
```

The code above returns the following results (http://codepad.org/yC47JLeC):

```
Array
(
    [0] => cup
    [1] => ounce
    [2] => cup
    [3] => ounce
    [4] => cup
    [5] => cup
    [6] => tablespoon
    [7] => tablespoon
    [8] => ounce
)
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to make it return the following results (http://codepad.org/MZXNOGnr):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 2
)
```

But to make it return the results in the "working" code, I had to put a 1 before the abbreviation characters so strpos wouldn't match those that aren't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The abbreviation 'c' for 'cup' is too much. You would need to check if it's a whole word. You could do that by embedding the search string in spaces, so look for `" c "` instead of `"c"`, or by using regex and matching on word boundaries.

Do note that if you change that, you will have to add 'ounces', 'cups' and 'tablespoons' (the plural form) to the needles too, otherwise you won't be able to find them. Actually, instead of writing an abbreviation, I would keep an array of 'variations' for each unit, so you'd get something like:

```
$needles = 
    array(
        '0' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'cup',
            'variations' => array('cups', 'cup', 'cp', 'c')
        ), 
    ...
```

You can then search for each variation of each needle.

Comment: I agree this would be the best approach, at the moment your 'c' is too vague of a match. (Hence why you're getting chocolate, cream and coconut matching).

Comment: I wound up storing serialized variations of each unit to the database just like your example, it's a lot more efficient than embedding white spaces between the string. Thanks you.